# tikz foreach loop only allowing one set of variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am currently trying to generate the following venn diagram:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, show background rectangle]
    \def\ellipsea{(0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
    \def\ellipseb{(-0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
    \def\ellipsec{(1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
    \def\ellipsed{(-1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
    \def\negating{(-4.5cm,-4.5cm) rectangle (4.5cm,4.5cm)}
    \node (a) at (-2.5cm,2.5cm) {C};
    \node (b) at (2.5cm,2.5cm) {B};
    \node (c) at (-3.5cm,1.5cm) {N};
    \node (d) at (3.5cm,1.5cm) {S};
    %~A~B~C~D
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %ABC~D      
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %AB~CD  
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %A~BCD  
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %~ABCD
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=blue,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %ABCD
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope   
    %AB~C~D
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=green,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %A~B~CD 
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=yellow,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %~AB~CD
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope       
    %~ABC~D
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=red,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope       
    %~A~BCD
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=orange,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %~AB~C~D
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=black,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %~A~B~CD
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea\negating;
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsec\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed;
        \fill[color=purple,opacity=0.2] \negating;
    \endscope
    %A~B~D
    \scope
        \clip \ellipsea;
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=red,opacity=0.5] \negating;
    \endscope
    %~BC~D
    \scope
        \clip \ellipseb\negating;
        \clip \ellipsec;
        \clip \ellipsed\negating;
        \fill[color=blue,opacity=0.5] \negating;
    \endscope


    \node (ABcd) at (0,1cm) {1};
    \node (aBCD) at (0.5cm,-2.25cm) {1};
    \node (AbcD) at (-1.2cm,-1.9cm) {1};
    \node (aBCd) at (1.2cm,-1.9cm) {2};
    \node (abCD) at (0,-3cm) {4};
    \node (abcD) at (-3cm,0cm) {1}; 
    \node (Abd) at (1.8cm,1.1cm) {3};
    \node (bCd) at (2.5cm,.5cm) {4};

    \draw \ellipsea;
    \draw \ellipseb;
    \draw \ellipsec;
    \draw \ellipsed;    

\end{tikzpicture}
```

using the tikz \foreach loop, for clarity, as so:

```
\foreach \abool/\bbool/\cbool/\dbool/\colchoose/\opchoose in {1/1/1/1,black,0.2}
            \scope  
            \ifnum \abool=1
                \clip \ellipsea;
                [\else \clip \ellipsea\negating;]
            \fi
            \ifnum \bbool=1
                \clip \ellipseb;
                [\else \clip \ellipseb\negating;]               
            \fi
            \ifnum \cbool=1
                \clip \ellipsec;
                [\else \clip \ellipsec\negating;]
            \fi
            \ifnum \dbool=1
                \clip \ellipsed;
                [\else \clip \ellipsed\negating;]
            \fi
            \fill[color=\colchoose,opacity=\opchoose] \negating;
            \endscope
```

To replace the long line of \scope s in the original piece. This seems to work fine, until I add multiple areas (such as {1/1/1/1/black/0.2,0/1/0/1,black,0.2}), in which case I get the following error:

```
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \end{tikzpicture}
! Missing \endgroup inserted.<inserted text>\endgroup \end{document}
```

Was wondering how to fix this or if there is something wrong with my code as I'm quite new to tikz.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine if

- you are careful with the values of the `\foreach` loop: The values for several variables of one iteration have to be separated by `/`, the values for different iterations by `,`.

  ```
  \foreach ... in {1/1/1/1/black/0.2,0/1/0/1/black/0.2}
  ```

  (You tried `{1/1/1/1/black/0.2,0/1/0/1,black,0.2}` instead.)
- Enclose the loop body in braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, show background rectangle]
    \def\ellipsea{(0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
    \def\ellipseb{(-0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
    \def\ellipsec{(1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
    \def\ellipsed{(-1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
    \def\negating{(-4.5cm,-4.5cm) rectangle (4.5cm,4.5cm)}
    \node (a) at (-2.5cm,2.5cm) {C};
    \node (b) at (2.5cm,2.5cm) {B};
    \node (c) at (-3.5cm,1.5cm) {N};
    \node (d) at (3.5cm,1.5cm) {S};



\foreach \abool/\bbool/\cbool/\dbool/\colchoose/\opchoose in {1/1/1/1/black/0.2,0/1/0/1/black/0.2}
{            \scope  
            \ifnum \abool=1
                \clip \ellipsea;
                [\else \clip \ellipsea\negating;]
            \fi
            \ifnum \bbool=1
                \clip \ellipseb;
                [\else \clip \ellipseb\negating;]               
            \fi
            \ifnum \cbool=1
                \clip \ellipsec;
                [\else \clip \ellipsec\negating;]
            \fi
            \ifnum \dbool=1
                \clip \ellipsed;
                [\else \clip \ellipsed\negating;]
            \fi
            \fill[color=\colchoose,opacity=\opchoose] \negating;
            \endscope
}


    \node (ABcd) at (0,1cm) {1};
    \node (aBCD) at (0.5cm,-2.25cm) {1};
    \node (AbcD) at (-1.2cm,-1.9cm) {1};
    \node (aBCd) at (1.2cm,-1.9cm) {2};
    \node (abCD) at (0,-3cm) {4};
    \node (abcD) at (-3cm,0cm) {1}; 
    \node (Abd) at (1.8cm,1.1cm) {3};
    \node (bCd) at (2.5cm,.5cm) {4};

    \draw \ellipsea;
    \draw \ellipseb;
    \draw \ellipsec;
    \draw \ellipsed;    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually I'm mostly ignoring the OPs question and providing a mostly more efficent way of specifying the diagram:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone} 
\tikzset{%
    venn/.code 2 args={\scope\def\c{#1}\def\n{}\tikzset{.. venn=#2@;}\endscope},
    .. venn/.code args={#1#2;}{%
        \ifx#1@%
            \path[fill=\c]\negating;
        \else%
            \ifx#1~
                \let\n=\negating
            \else%
                \clip \csname ellipse#1\endcsname\n;
                \def\n{}%
            \fi%
            \tikzset{.. venn=#2;}%
        \fi}}
\def\ellipsea{(0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
\def\ellipseb{(-0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
\def\ellipsec{(1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
\def\ellipsed{(-1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
\def\negating{(-4.5cm,-4.5cm) rectangle (4.5cm,4.5cm)}
\newcommand\venn[2][]{\tikzset{venn={#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\venn [red]       {abcd}
\venn [yellow]    {~abcd}
\venn [pink]      {a~bcd}
\venn [green]     {ab~cd}
\venn [orange]    {abc~d}
\venn [purple]    {~a~bcd}
\venn [blue]      {~ab~cd}
\venn [magenta]   {~abc~d}
\venn [olive]     {a~b~cd}
\venn [violet]    {a~bc~d}
\venn [teal]      {ab~c~d}
\venn [brown]     {~a~b~cd}
\venn [teal]      {~a~bc~d}
\venn [lime]      {~ab~c~d}
\venn [darkgray]  {a~b~c~d}
\venn [lightgray] {~a~b~c~d}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's a variant which (a) still doesn't answer the OPs question but (b) enables specification as a bit sequence, e.g., `1101`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone} 
\tikzset{%
    venn/.code 2 args={\scope\def\c{#1}\tikzset{.. venn/.expanded=#2@;abcd@;}\endscope},
    .. venn/.code args={#1#2;#3#4;}{%
        \ifx#1@%
            \path[fill=\c]\negating;
        \else%
            \ifcase#1
                \clip \csname ellipse#3\endcsname\negating;
            \or%
                \clip \csname ellipse#3\endcsname;
            \fi%
            \tikzset{.. venn=#2;#4;}%
        \fi%
}}
\def\ellipsea{(0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
\def\ellipseb{(-0.5cm,0) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
\def\ellipsec{(1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=50]}
\def\ellipsed{(-1.5cm,-1cm) ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm, rotate=-50]}
\def\negating{(-4.5cm,-4.5cm) rectangle (4.5cm,4.5cm)}
\newcommand\venn[2][]{\tikzset{venn={#1}{#2}}}
\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\r=rnd;\g=rnd;\b=rnd;}] in {0,...,15}{
  \definecolor{tmp}{rgb}{\r,\g,\b}
  \pgfmathdectobase\n{\i}{2}%
  \venn[tmp]{\n}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The action of the 'parser' (i.e., the `venn` and `venn ..` keys) can perhaps be best explained with an example.

Consider what happens when using `\venn{1100}`.

The `venn` key 'calls' `.. venn=1100@;abcd@;`. The `abcd` are the suffixes of the `\ellipsea`, `\ellipseb`, `\ellipsec` and `\ellipsed` commands. The `@` characters are (arbitrary) sentinel characters which enable detecting when the end of a sequence has been reached. The `;` characters are delineators to mark the end of the strings. Then consider each iteration in turn:

1. The arguments to the `.. venn` key are

   ```
   #1 -> 1 #2 -> 100@ 
   #3 -> a #4 -> bcd@
   ```
2. The arguments to the `.. venn` key are

   ```
   #1 -> 1 #2 -> 00@ 
   #3 -> b #4 -> cd@
   ```
3. The arguments to the `.. venn` key are

   ```
   #1 -> 0 #2 -> 0@ 
   #3 -> c #4 -> d@
   ```
4. The arguments to the `.. venn` key are

   ```
   #1 -> 0 #2 -> @ 
   #3 -> d #4 -> @
   ```
5. The arguments to the `.. venn` key are

   ```
   #1 -> @ #2 ->  
   #3 -> @ #4 ->
   ```

Having reached the sentinel character the parser terminates.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've definitely learnt a lot about using tikzset through this example :) I was wondering if you had the time to explain the following code in more detail as I'm a bit lost:

venn/.code 2 args={\scope\def\c{#1}\tikzset{.. venn/.expanded=#2@;abcd@;}\endscope},
    .. venn/.code args={#1#2;#3#4;}

specifically how #2@;abcd@; works. Thanks!

Comment: @JacksonGoerner see the updated answer.